# How to add paragraph and border using OpenPDF

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, openpdf

I am using OpenPDF to generate PDF document with header and footer images added to PDF. A paragraph needs to be added to center of the PDF with some of the text content is dynamic based on input request and everything needs surrounded by border. I am able to generate the PDf with header and footer added to it but having problems adding paragraph to center of the pdf and border. Any help is appreciated.

I tried different ways by adding table or using canvas but could not solve it.

```
   public void generatePDF(String firstName, String lastName){
    try {
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
        //setting font family, color
        Font font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC, Color.RED);
        doc.open();
        addHeaderImageToPDF(doc,writer);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Hello! This PDF is created for "+firstName+" "+lastName, font);
        para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        doc.add(para);
        addFooterImageToPDF(doc,writer);
        addBorderToPDF(doc);
        doc.close();
        writer.close();   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

private void addBorderToPDF(Document document){
    Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(531.5f,820,38.5f,0); // you can resize rectangle 
    rect.enableBorderSide(1);
    rect.enableBorderSide(2);
    rect.enableBorderSide(4);
    rect.enableBorderSide(8);
    rect.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
    rect.setBorderWidth(2);
    document.add(rect);
}

private void addHeaderImageToPDF(Document document, PdfWriter writer){
    try {
        Image image = Image.getInstance(HEADER_IMAGE_PATH);
        //image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE_PATH);
        image.scalePercent(50f);
        //image.setAbsolutePosition(0, (float) (PageSize.A4.getHeight() - 20.0));
        image.setAbsolutePosition(40, 675);
        System.out.println(image.getScaledHeight());
        document.add(image);
        image.scaleToFit(100f, 100f);
        //document.add(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addFooterImageToPDF(Document document, PdfWriter writer){
    try {
        Image image = Image.getInstance(FOOTER_IMAGE_PATH);
        //image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE_PATH);
        image.scalePercent(50f);
        //image.setAbsolutePosition(0, (float) (PageSize.A4.getHeight() - 20.0));
        image.setAbsolutePosition(40, 450);
        System.out.println(image.getScaledHeight());
        document.add(image);
        image.scaleToFit(100f, 100f);
        //document.add(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Wanted to add paragraph at the center and whole content of PDF should be surrounded by border with dark blue color. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By also using the [tag:itext] and [tag:pdfbox] tags do you imply that a solution using itext 5 or pdfbox 2 would also be on for you?

Comment: Yes, itext or pdfbox also works. we have flexibility to use any API we want.

Answer (score 2):

As the given tags [itext](/questions/tagged/itext), [pdfbox](/questions/tagged/pdfbox), and [openpdf](/questions/tagged/openpdf) imply some freedom of choice of PDF library, here an example for creating a centered paragraph with a dark blue border using iText 7 (v7.1.7):

#### A centered paragraph with a border

```
String firstName = "Mister";
String lastName = "Nine";
try (   PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new File("CenterParagraph.pdf"));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)   ) {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello! This PDF is created for "+firstName+" "+lastName);
    paragraph.setWidth(100).setBorder(new SolidBorder(new DeviceRgb(0f, 0f, 0.6f), 3));
    PageSize box = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();
    document.showTextAligned(paragraph, (box.getLeft() + box.getRight()) / 2, (box.getTop() + box.getBottom()) / 2,
            TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
}
```

*([ShowTextAtPosition](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/ShowTextAtPosition.java#L40) test `testShowCenteredBorderedParagraph`)*

resulting in a

[image: screen shot]

in the middle of the page.

#### A centered paragraph with header and footer images and a page border

```
String firstName = "Mister";
String lastName = "Nine";

Image img = null;
try (   InputStream imageResource = IMAGE_INPUT_STREAM ) {
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(imageResource));
    img = new Image(data);
    img.scaleToFit(100f, 100f);
}

try (   PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new File("CenterParagraphWithExtras.pdf"));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)   ) {
    PageSize box = pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize();

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello! This PDF is created for "+firstName+" "+lastName);
    paragraph.setWidth(100);
    document.showTextAligned(paragraph, (box.getLeft() + box.getRight()) / 2, (box.getTop() + box.getBottom()) / 2,
            TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);

    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.getLastPage());
    Rectangle borderRectangle = new Rectangle(box.getLeft() + 5, box.getBottom() + 5, box.getWidth() - 10, box.getHeight() - 10);
    pdfCanvas.setColor(new DeviceRgb(0f, 0f, 0.6f), false);
    pdfCanvas.setLineWidth(3);
    pdfCanvas.rectangle(borderRectangle);
    pdfCanvas.stroke();

    img.setFixedPosition(box.getLeft() + 40, box.getTop() - 150);
    document.add(img);
    img.setFixedPosition(box.getLeft() + 40, box.getBottom() + 50);
    document.add(img);
}
```

resulting in

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you also help me to add header and footer images and whole content surrounded by border?

Comment: @Mr9 *"Can you also help me to add header and footer images and whole content surrounded by border?"* - see the edit of my answer.

Comment: @mkl Could you please help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980765/rectangular-header-footer-block-on-every-page-of-pdf-using-openpdf